# GoLang import forked 3rd party

Tags: go, import, fork

My case is bit tricky.

I'm using two 3rd parties, let's call them **A** and **B**, also **A** is using **B**.
Now, I forked **B** so I've **Forked_B**.
And I need that **A** will use **Forked_B**.
Is there a way to do it? to trick the system? (except to fork also **A**).

Thanks

I though to fork A also and use the Forked_B..

Comment: For executables: Use a replace directive in go.mod. For libraries: You cannot do this.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might want to be using the Go `replace` directive, see the documentation for it here: https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace. That said, usually the `replace` directive is not the long term solution.

If you are using A, and A depends on B, and you have a fork of B, you should also fork A and update its dependency to B to use your fork. Then in the code you're referencing A you can instead reference your fork of A.

Here's an example of how to use the `replace` directive in a `go.mod`

```bash
module github.com/company/mypackage

go 1.20

replace github.com/vendor/b => ../path/to/your/fork/of/b

require (
  github.com/vendor/a v1.0.0
  github.com/vendor/b v1.0.0
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
For the future ones..
Refer this also

https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace

Comment: @KobiGana That is the link that I included in my answer. If my answer answered your question please mark it as the accepted answer.